# scons perform action only if target is not present

Tags: scons

Is there a way to have scons perform an action that only depends on the existence of the target?

More specifically, I'd like to download a file using `wget`, but only if it isn't already there. So ideally I'd have some `Builder` that takes the url as a source and the local filename as the target and then calls something like this:

```
wget $SOURCE_URL -O $TARGET
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SCons Command() builder](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-builders-commands), as follows:

```
source_url = 'put url here'
Command(target='local_file_name', source=None, action='wget %s -O $TARGET'%(source_url))
```

SCons will parse the action string replacing '$TARGET' with the target passed to the Command() builder.

Comment: Hmm... "TypeError: Command() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)"

Comment: @juniper- Its missing the source, which can be left empty. I'll update the answer.

Comment: It works. I just had a sys.exit(1) after this set of commands to skip the rest of the file for debugging, and didn't realize that it wouldn't execute everything up to there. Removing it allows it to work just fine. Thanks!!